# How to call a function from a list?

Tags: python, function

For example, I have the following list:

```
method = [fun1, fun2, fun3, fun4]
```

Then I show a menu where the user must select a number from 1-4 (`len(method)`). If the user selects `i`, I have to use the function `funi`. How can I do that?

Eg.

```
A=['hello','bye','goodbye']
def hello(n):
 print n**2
def bye(n):
 print n**3
def goodbye(n):
 print n**4
```

If I want to call the function `bye` by the array A, using

```
>>>A[1](7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
A[2](5)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I use the names saved in `A` to call my functions? because every method is saved in a string.

Comment: Do you mean `funi = method[i-1]` (indices are zero-based in Python)? Perhaps try reading a Python tutorial on lists?

Comment: yes, I just need the way to call the method, the index is easy to fix, thanks !

Comment: Edited for understand

Comment: Why are you storing *strings* in the list, rather than *the functions themselves* (`A = [hello, bye, goodbye]`)?

Comment: Use `A=[hello, bye, goodbye]` instead. In this way, you store the methods, not their names. And then you can use them like `A[1](17)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see...

You call a function fn by using parens () as in `fn()`

You access an item from a list by the indexing operator [] as in `lst[idx]`

So, by combining the two `lst[idx](*args)`

EDIT

Python list indices are zero-based, so for the first item is 0, the second 1, etc... If the user selects 1-4, you'll have to subtract one.

EDIT

Given the clarification, the following can be done

```
def method1():
    pass

def method2():
    pass


methods = [method1, method2]
```

And you can use the logic above. This way you won't have to mess with actual resolving the string of a name of the function to the actual function.

Keep in mind that functions in python are first class so you can store a reference of them to a list (what we do in `methods=[]` line)

Comment: @RodrigoLópez I'm thinking in 0-based indexing :)

Comment: In question he selects from 1 to 4

Comment: I just gave an example, exactly I'm using: 
    method=['LU','CHOLESKY','Gauss', 'Gaussnopivot', 'Gaussconpivot', 'Gaussconviotparcial', 'Gaussconpivotcomp']

Comment: Where have you defined the methods ?

Comment: @LuisFelipeVillavicencioLopez they're strings, **not** methods. Are they the *names* of methods?

Comment: so the elements in your list are not methods, but *strings* representing those methods. How do you call the method `'Gauss'`, for instance?

Comment: Yes, That is my problem, I just edited with an example

Answer (score 2):

In your list are not functions but strings (which have "randomly" the same name as the functions). Just put the functions inside the list:

```
def hello():
    pass

mylist = [hello]
mylist[0]()
```

If you need the name of a function you can use `a.__name__` e.g.

```
def hello():
    pass
mylist = [hello]
print("Available functions:")
for function in mylist:
    print(function.__name__)
```

Comment: But I need to use the name of the functions because I print a Menu where every method is enumerate, and I call the method by their enumeration.

Comment: Use `myfunc.__name__` to get the name of a function as a string.

Comment: e.g  print myfun.(hello)   will print 'hello' ?

Comment: If your function is called `hello` `print(hello.__name__)` will print `"hello"`